# How to change my Heroku + MediaWiki database from clearDB one to a local DB

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, wiki

I build a wiki using MediaWiki. Initially, I used a remote database (clearDB), as setup was faster. I now want to migrate the data, and use a db local to the server instead.

My current db settings in `Localsettings.php`

```
## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "us-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XX.cleardb.net";
$wgDBname = "heroku_XXXXXXXXX";
$wgDBuser = "XXXXXXXXX";
$wgDBpassword = "XXXXXXXXXX";
```

Obviously, if I just "changed" the `$wgDBserver` to `localhost`, it won't work.

What needs to be done to migrate the old data and default MediaWiki architecture to a new db local to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `mysqldump` on your old data store and save the pure SQL locally.

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p -h us-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XX.cleardb.net heroku_XXXXXXXX > /tmp/wikidump.sql
```

Then on your local server, recreate the heroku_XXXXXXXXX DB t

```
CREATE DATABASE heroku_XXXXXXXX (exact same name);
use heroku_XXXXXXX;
source /tmp/wikidump.sql
```

This will do the trick.

I sometimes look inside the dump (`/tmp/wikidump.sql`) with a text editor to make sure no references to `cleardb.net` exists an change them. That's just me! Otherwise follow:

[Change external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659394/how-to-update-all-external-links-after-migrating-a-mediawiki?rq=1)